# @OneToOne with Lazy

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 entities:
parent entity:

```
@Entity
public class Parent{

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentId", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Car car;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Kid> kids;
```

and kid entity:

```
@Entity
public class Kid{

@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
private Parent parentId;
```

and car entity:

```
@Entity
public class Car{

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
private Parent parentId;
```

The database is:

```
Parent: ID
Kid: ID, PARENT_ID
Car: ID, PARENT_ID
```

each parent that has a car - doesn't have any kids and vice-versa - each parent that has kids doesn't have a car.

The problem is that if a Parent has many kids - on each access to a kid, redundant queries that trying to get a car by its parentId are invoked by Hibernate.
(e.g. SELECT * FROM CAR WHERE PARENT_ID = ?)

I tried to prevent this from happening with adding the LAZY to the car at the Parent entity, along with PrimaryKeyJoinColumn at the Car entity - but now when I'm trying to access the Parent from the Car it gives me null.

What can I do if I want it to ignore the Car when accessing the Parent via the Kid, and not getting Parent = null when accessing the Parent from the Car?

Thanks

Comment: In Hibernate, lazy loading is the default. But when loading lazily, you need to populate everything you need during the same transaction. However, you should get an exception instead of null when accessing uninitialized lazy fields.

Could you share some code? Where do you get the null, are the entities serialized in between? What is the database used?